# Eco repeatable field with image in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to echo repeatable feilds in Wordpress but I have images in the repeatable field.  I want to echo all the images in this repeatable feild into a template.  THe fields are in a custom meta box in the admin panel. How can I output/echo these.

This is what i came up with:

```
 <?php $custom_repeatable = unserialize($post_meta_data['custom_repeatable']                     
     [0]); ?>
     <?php echo '<ul class="custom_repeatable">';
     foreach ($custom_repeatable as $string) {
 echo '&ltli>'.$string.'</li>';
       }
        </ul>'; ?>
```

Comment: This code is really strange, check the docs about [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), and search for real life examples here or in [wordpress.se]. Try to start with some already tested and working code. I'm voting to close this Question as *too localized*.

Comment: The code came from a wpTuts tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields/     I can output the repeatable fields just fine with this code but I need to output images that are in the fields. I tweaked the tuts code to allow images and they are populated int eh repeatable fields I just can t get them to output.